# can a spaceship decelerate relativistically?

Tags: speed-of-light, relativity, lorentz-symmetry

Say I have a spaceship, and on board is a laboratory set to accomplish some sort of experiment, simulation, or computation which might take upwards of a few hundred years or more to complete.  Instead of waiting for the results, could it be possible to slow the ship down relativistically, such that the ship's local clock is accelerated significantly when compared to the earth's?

When I try to research this all I get are equations describing the opposite situation.  How does relativity describe relative deceleration?

Of course you'd have to pick up the results again after the experiment is over . . . but aside from this I'm having trouble conceptualizing what such a journey would entail.  I don't understand in what 'direction' a ship would 'thrust' if it where to set the earth at, say, 0.5c, and how that would differ from accelerating?  If the speed of light is invariant to any relative speed, than would that suggest light does not move at all and our attribution of 'speed' is merely an anthropic convention?  I could, say, set a ship against the galactic rotation, but wouldn't this still be an accelerated frame of reference, and therefore reverse my desired effect of time dilation?  Or, does slowing down relative to the speed of light entail some exotic sort of matter phase transition into a condensate or some such speculative something?  It seems like such a simple question but I'm right baffled!

Edit:

I understand the twin paradox, I think, and that is why I am having trouble.  My question is similar to the twin paradox; except both twins are *born on the ship* after it has already been accelerated to relativistic speed.  If acceleration where the same as deceleration, than it wouldn't matter if our twins were born on the ship or the earth, the effect of switching between frames of reference and switching back should be the same.  Unfortunately, I can't conceptually rectify this.  One twin returns to the earth by decelerating to the earth's speed.  The visiting twin misses their sibling so much they return to their birthship.  This traveling twin should be older, reflective of their time spent at the decelerated reference.  This is the opposite of what the twin paradox would suggest, where the traveling twin remains younger.

Comment: I'm finding it very hard to figure out exactly where your confusion lies, but let's start at the beginning:  If we arbitrarily choose a direction (say to your right) and call it "forward" then a velocity of .5 means you're moving to the right at speed .5, and a velocity of -.5 means you're moving to the left at speed .5.  It's only the speed, not the plus/minus sign, that affects the factor by which I'll say your clocks have slowed down (and also, of course, the factor by which you'll say my clocks have slowed down).  Does this help?

Comment: okay, I added another paragraph.  Let me know if I'm starting to make any more sense.

Comment: Re your new paragraph:  The twins are born on the ship, so it's easiest to do everything in the ship's frame of reference.  The ship is stationary.  One twin travels to earth (which requires some acceleration), then turns around and travels back (which requires some further acceleration).   On his return, the twin who accelerated finds that he is younger than the twin who stayed put on the spaceship.  You say that you understand the twin paradox --- but this *is* the twin paradox, just with the earth renamed "spaceship" and the spaceship renamed "earth".

Comment: (Note too that the relative motion of the spaceship and the earth is irrelevant.  All that matters in the twin paradox is that you travel somewhere and come back.)

Comment: Indeed, I've swapped spaceship and earth.  Let 1sy be a ship year = 100ey of years on earth.  we'll say T1 stays on the ship, while T2 goes to earth.  T2 spends 100ey on earth and returns to ship.  Relative to T1, the trip is 1sy.  relative to T2, the trip is 100ey.  T2 is younger?

Comment: I know that you believe you understand the twin paradox, but at this point it is crystal clear that you don't.  There are plenty of places to read up on it.  Once you do, I promise this will all make sense.

Comment: I've read and read and it still makes no sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29323/discussion-between-punkerplunk-and-willo).

Answer (score 2):

In SR, it is not acceleration which causes time dilation, so whether you accelerate or decelerate makes no difference. What matters is relative velocity, and the calculation for the difference factor, $$\gamma = \sqrt{1 -\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$$ produces a result which is independent of sign.

So the answer is no. And actually, I'm not at all sure what "relativistic deceleration" means. Accelerating to, or decelerating from, relativistic velocities is only important for resolving the Twin Paradox in showing that the two travelers undergo different travel conditions, so their ultimate relative ages is in fact different. And in this context, the "young" twin undergoes both acceleration and deceleration.

Comment: so what determines which twin is to be the younger?

Comment: Google "Twin Paradox"

Comment: I know about twin paradox.  That's not what I'm asking.

Comment: "*it is not acceleration which causes time dilation*" - are you sure?

Comment: @punkerplunk = Acceleration produces velocity, to be sure, so without acceleration two observers initially at rest with respect to each other will not have to deal with relativistic effects. But SR deals with observers who are not accelerating with respect to each other, so acceleration does not, in this context, cause time dilation. That said, a clock which is accelerating wrt an observer will show changes in rate, but those changes are enormously smaller than for fractional c velocities for any acceleration which we can produce on a macroscopic body.

Comment: @punkerplunk - "so what determines which twin is to be the younger?" vs "I know about twin paradox. That's not what I'm asking" Well, if you understand the twin paradox, you know which twin is to be the younger. If you don't know, you don't understand the twin paradox.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you're on Earth watching the spaceship. The spaceship departs at time zero and returns at some time $t = T$. In between its departure and return the spaceship's velocity is given by some function $v(t)$. The time measured by the astronauts on the spaceship, $\tau$, is given by:

$$ \tau = \int_0^{T} \sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2(t) }{c^2}} dt \tag{1} $$

Deriving equation (1) is straightforward but involves a few concepts alien to non-nerds, so let's just accept the equation now. Anyhow, let's see what the implications for the astronauts on the ship are.

Firstly a quick consistency check. Suppose the spaceship isn't moving so $v= 0$. In that case the integral becomes:

$$ \tau = \int_0^{T} \sqrt{1 - \frac{0}{c^2}} dt = \int_0^{T} 1 \, dt = T $$

and the ship's time is the same as ours - so far so good. Now suppose the spaceship is moving at some velocity $v(t)$ that changes with time as the spaceship accelerates and decelerates. The velocity $v$ can be positive or negative, but $v^2$ is always positive and that means:

$$ 1 - \frac{v^2(t)}{c^2} \le 1 $$

So we are integrating something that can at most be equal to one and is in general less than one. It doesn't matter how $v$ varies with time, if $v$ is non-zero then the integral must be less that $T$ and that means:

$$ \tau \le T $$

The time on the spaceship cannot be greater than the time measured on Earth or put another way time always runs more slowly on the spaceship.

So there is no way to speed up the time on your spaceship to get the experiment done more quickly.

**Response to comment:**

You ask what happens when travelling at (for example) $v = 0.5c$ for a time T (300 seconds). If $v$ is a constant my equation (1) becomes:

$$ \tau = \int_0^{T} \sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}} dt = T\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}} = \frac{T}{\gamma} $$

and the equation:

$$ \tau = \frac{T}{\gamma} $$

is just the standard equation for time dilation when moving at constant speed.

In general, if you have a known form for the function $v(t)$ then you can plug into equation (1) and get an equation for the time dilation.

Comment: Okay, let me attempt to un-golf this.  If I have already chosen my velocity in terms of c, can I simplify the right hand side of that equation? say T = 300; v = 0.5c; tau = sqrt(0.5*300).  >>[Y/n]?

Comment: @punkerplunk: I've extended my answer to respond to your comment

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between acceleration and deceleration, except in the difference in direction. This is no different from non-relativistic physics. With regards to your application, what you would do is to perform the calculation on Earth and you would use the twin-paradox and send the person who wants to know the answer on a long journey. He would come back young and refreshed, while centuries would have gone by on Earth.

Comment: that's the opposite of what I'm asking, though.

Comment: Sometimes the opposite of what people are asking for is what they actually need. I am not trying to offend you with suggesting what you may already know. I am aware what you were asking for, but honestly, that's what one would do if this was an even borderline realistic scenario. Truthfully, relativistic spaceflight is simply not going to happen, one way or another.

Comment: You are most likely 100% correct.  I don't want to sound offended either I just feel like i'm not being clear enough.  It might not be realistic, but if you could theoretically accelerate a ship to 0.5c, couldn't you than decelerate a ship such that the earth traveling at 0.5c?

Comment: What you are asking for is accelerated travel into the future. The twin-paradox does that, but at an enormous energetic cost. You can achieve the same result in biological systems by lowering the temperature and keeping a "traveler" in suspended animation for the required timespan. That's much easier and cheaper to do technically. Alternatively you can design a 100 times faster computer. That's the easiest and cheapest solution. :-)

Comment: @punkerplunk:  This answer is *not* the opposite of what you're asking; it's *exactly* what you're asking.  If you're on earth, and you want to learn the outcome of a long experiment, you can travel away from earth at a very high speed and then return.  If you're on a spaceship, and you want to learn the outcome of a long experiment, you can travel away from the spaceship at a very high speed and then return.  The fact that your homebase is called "spaceship" instead of "earth" changes absolutely nothing.